# JAVA WS-SECURITY SOAP DHL Tracking service

Tags: java, api, soap, apache-axis, ws-security

I've successfully managed to get the responses from FedEx and UPS APIs, however dhl ones is driving me crazy.
Well below is my code, which is generating following request.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" standalone="no"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
<ns2:trackShipmentRequest xmlns:ns2="http://scxgxtt.phx-dc.dhl.com/glDHLExpressTrack/providers/services/trackShipment">
<trackingRequest>
<TrackingRequest xmlns="http://www.dhl.com">
<Request xmlns="">
<ServiceHeader>
<MessageTime>2011-09-01T20:40:36.334+02:00</MessageTime>
<MessageReference>123456789012345678901234567890</MessageReference>
</ServiceHeader>
</Request>
<LevelOfDetails xmlns="">ALL_CHECK_POINTS</LevelOfDetails>
</TrackingRequest>
</trackingRequest>
</ns2:trackShipmentRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What I am actually missing is the header section like this (tested in SOAP-UI):

```
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-12">
<wsse:Username>xxx</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">xxx</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header
```

What do I need to add to the code in order to get the header section in the SOAP request being sent to DHL server?

Below is my actual code.
It's standard axis2 wsdl2java:

```
public class abc {

/**
 * @param args

 * @param String ref 
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","F:\\eclipse\\terefere\\testkeystore");
    System.setProperty("javaxdhlrequest2.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","123456"); 

    GblDHLExpressTrackStub stub = new GblDHLExpressTrackStub();

    System.out.println("3");        
    System.out.println("5");

    TrackShipmentRequest trackShipmentRequest = new TrackShipmentRequest();

    TrackShipmentRequestE trackshipmentrequeste = new TrackShipmentRequestE();
    PubTrackingRequest pubtrackingequest = new PubTrackingRequest();
    System.out.println("6");
    TrackingRequest dhlrequest = new TrackingRequest();
    System.out.println("7");
    Request request = new Request();
    ServiceHeader header =new ServiceHeader();
    System.out.println("8");
    Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    AWBNumber awbnumber = new AWBNumber();

    awbnumber.setAWBNumber("2510305906");

    LevelOfDetails level = null;        
    level= LevelOfDetails.ALL_CHECK_POINTS;

    MessageReference message = new MessageReference();

    message.setMessageReference("123456789012345678901234567890");

                                header.setMessageReference(message);
                                header.setMessageTime(rightNow);
                        request.setServiceHeader(header);
                    //dhlrequest.setAWBNumber(awb);
                    dhlrequest.setLevelOfDetails(level);
                    dhlrequest.setRequest(request);

            pubtrackingequest.setTrackingRequest(dhlrequest);
        trackShipmentRequest.setTrackingRequest(pubtrackingequest);
    trackshipmentrequeste.setTrackShipmentRequest(trackShipmentRequest);

    GblDHLExpressTrackCallbackHandler callb = new GblDHLExpressTrackCallbackHandler() {
    };

    stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setUserName("abc");
    stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setPassword("abc");
        stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, false);

        stub._getServiceClient().engageModule("rampart");       
        stub.starttrackShipmentRequest(trackshipmentrequeste, callb);
        System.out.println("11,5");
        stub.trackShipmentRequest(trackshipmentrequeste);

        System.out.println("13");
    }   
}
```

Comment: Solved !!  

axis2 client context was to be added, so adding below gets me reply from server

ConfigurationContext configurationContext = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem("F:\\eclipse\\axis2-1.6.0\\repository\\modules\\rampart-1.6.0.mar","F:\\eclipse\\axis2-1.6.0\\conf\\axis2.xml");
  GblDHLExpressTrackStub stub = new GblDHLExpressTrackStub(configurationContext);
  
  ServiceClient sc = stub._getServiceClient();
  sc.engageModule("rampart");
  
  Options options = sc.getOptions();
  options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, false);
  sc.setOptions(options);